# How to connect to Redis Cluster using Quarkus Redis and port forwarding?

Tags: java, redis, vert.x, quarkus

I'm trying to debug a "change hostname on redirect" issue with [Quarkus Redis](https://quarkus.io/guides/redis)

This works fine:

```
package org.acme;

import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Command;
import io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Redis;
import io.vertx.mutiny.redis.client.Request;
import io.vertx.redis.client.RedisOptions;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@Path("/redis")
public class RedisCommandsTest {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RedisCommandsTest2.class);

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public void hello() throws InterruptedException {
    var vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    final RedisOptions options = new RedisOptions()
        .addConnectionString("redis://127.0.0.1:7000")
        .addConnectionString("redis://127.0.0.1:7001")
        .addConnectionString("redis://127.0.0.1:7002");

    Redis.createClient(vertx, options)
        .connect()
        .subscribe().with(conn -> {
          conn.send(Request.cmd(Command.GET).arg("KEY1"))
              .subscribe().with(response -> {
                  System.out.println(response);
              });
        });
  }
}
```

This doesn't work

```
//application.properties
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://127.0.0.1:7000,redis://127.0.0.1:7001,redis://127.0.0.1:7002
quarkus.redis.client-type: cluster
quarkus.redis.max-pool-size: 4

import io.quarkus.redis.client.reactive.ReactiveRedisClient;

reactiveRedisClient.get("KEY1")
    .subscribe().with(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
    });
```

Gives this error

> 2021-11-12 16:40:08,059 ERROR [io.qua.mut.run.MutinyInfrastructure]
> (vert.x-eventloop-thread-15) Mutiny had to drop the following
> exception: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Failed to connect
> to all nodes of the cluster

Which digging into Vert.x show this to be the actual error

> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: No
> route to host: /10.100.23.75:6379

Which looks similar to this error but I can't find a solution https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/issues/223

(I'm port forwarding from Kubernetes cluster)

The real question is why does one way work but not the other? Maybe there's some property I'm missing?

Comment: Are you running all that stack inside a kubernetes cluster? I mean quarkus + redis cluster. Could you provide more detail on this. I believe (IMHO) there might be an issue with `127.0.0.1`as the redis ip. Also redis nodes may be announcing themselves using the container IP, not the service. That behaviour is configured by `replica-announce-ip` parameter as stated [here](https://redis.io/topics/replication)

Comment: The strange thing is that extension doesn't work but pure Mutiny does - for some reason extension tries to follow the redirects but Mutiny does not. In my case Redis is inside K8 cluster but Quarkus is not because I'm testing. If everyone is inside it's fine because the IPs can be followed.